# Unable to write to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning how to write data to Firebase RealTime Database, but after some tests I can't put new data into my DB and I haven't had any error from the app.
Here is my code:

```
MainActivity.class


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText mName;
    Button button;
    DatabaseReference root;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mName = findViewById(R.id.etMess);
        button = findViewById(R.id.btInvia);

        root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("student");
        
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                insertData();
            }
        });

    }

    private void insertData() {
        String name = mName.getText().toString();

        Dati dati = new Dati(name);

        root.push().setValue(dati);
Toast.makeText(this,"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

```
Dati.class
public class Dati {

    String name;

    public Dati(String name) {

        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Rules from my db are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I tried to read something from DB using get() function, but I had an error:
`get for query / falling back to disk cache after error: Client is offline java.lang.Exception: Client is offline`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Or you can get the string `name` using `dati.getName()` not using `dati`

Comment: Everything seems ok. Make sure your connection is stable. Sometimes emulator creates problem while reading or writing in database. You can reinstall app on emulator.

Comment: what you're trying to do is set the value to firebase using a POJO whereas your model has only a getter